# Обработка несколько единовременных тачов

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет. У меня на UI есть джойстик и несколько кнопок. Дело в том что у меня геймплей завязан на единовременном нажатии несколько тачов. С помощью джойстика передвигается и может делать что то попутно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что есть зона нажатия на джойстик и кирку. Когда идёт нажатие на зону джойстика то на месте тача центруется сам джойстик и соответственно игроку нужно только уже начать движение и персонаж пойдет по заданному курсу. Тоже самое с киркой, если произведётся нажатие в зоне кирки то  отцентруется по тачу сама кирка. И когда при нажатом джойстике я нажимаю кирку то позиции начинают скакать то тачам, так как я использую Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint вместе с Input.mousePosition.
Эту проблему я уже обнаружил на смартфоне.

Вся соль в том что я(наверное) должен обрабатывать нажатия с помощью Input.GetTouch. И я немного не понимаю как мне правильно всё это дело реализовать, так как нужно понимать что я нажал джойстик и затем кирку. Вот например, я нажал джойстик(Input.touchCount = 1) и немного его сдвинул чтобы начать движение персонажа в игре. Если идёт одно нажатие то в принципе обработать это легко. Но если к этому добавить кирку или другую кнопку(тогда уже идёт массив тачов). Потом я отпустил джойстик и опять его нажал и получается что индексы в массиве уже поменялись. Как мне отслеживать это? Каждый раз копаться в массиве и сравнивать тачи по позициям? Возможно для кого то это банально, но на данном этапе мне не ясно. Помогите добрым словом или же примером.

Answer (score 0):

когда ты ткнул пальцем в экран, то в рамках одного тычка  fingerId у Touch будет одинаковый.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос